# Correlating a drop-down list

Tags: drop-down-menu, jmeter, correlation

I have a drop-down list in which the values are:

```
store:[ ['1', 'Probation'], ['2', 'Confirmed'], ['3', 'Trainee'], ['4', 'Contract'] ],
```

I want to split the string using a split function to get:

```
[['1', 'Probation'],
['2', 'Confirmed'],
['3', 'Trainee'],
['4', 'Contract'] ],
```

Then, I can use regular expressions and pull the values 1, 2, 3, 4, or probation, confirmed, etc. and pass it to a request.

Can anybody help me with this?  I want to know where exactly I can see the string after splitting, where I should call it, and how to use regular expressions for the split string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split the string to do a regular expression on it - you'd just add the Regex post processor as a child of your request.

If you do want to do the split, you'd want to add a post-processor BeanShell Assertion as a container for your code.